# Duplicate link titles, how do I find the one I want?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a list of links on the left of the webapp I'm automating. One has a main menu item called "User Management". There is a second link, the one I want that has the same name but is a sub-item off of a different main item.

Of course if I try identifying it by link title it will always find the first one, the main one which is not what I want. I've tried xpath and a few other things but I can't figure it out. Here is the html for both.

```
 <td id="mainleftlinkzoneover" class="mainleftlinks" width="151" title="User Management">  User Management</td>

 <td class="currentsubleftlinks" valign="top" title="User Management">  User Management</td>
```

Keep in mind this isn't the only link under the class currentsubleftlinks, there are three others with a different title.

I wish there was a way I could say if (link title is User Management) and (td class is currentsubleftlinks) then pick that one and click it.

Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: Were any of the answers below helpful?

Answer (score 0):

**Your first element has an ID** so you can use it to locate the element. 
In CssSelector it will be "#mainleftlinkzoneover"

To locate the second one you can try to use CssSelector again or XPath.

**With Css you can try to locate a specific child**: `".currentsubleftlinks:nth-child(2)"`

**With XPath try this:** `"//td[@title='User Management']"`

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using title names at all, even when it has a unique value. I think that a more structural approach is favorable, for example with CSS. Using CSS you can gradually narrow down the area you are interested in and thus avoid possible issues with elements names. In this case you didn't provide the whole page so I can't give a full example but the element you mentioned can be selected like this:

```
@FindBy(css = SOME_ENCLOSING_CSS + "$.currentsubleftlinks")
private WebElement elementName;
```

Answer (score 0):

for first, use the below as cssSelector:

```
#mainleftlinkzoneover.mainleftlinks[width^='151']
```

to click on second, use below as cssSelector:

```
td.currentsubleftlinks[valign^='top']
```